# C language. Array left border [1..] insted of [0..]

Tags: c, arrays

Stupid C language forces all arrays to start from 0th element. How to declare (without initialization) array [1..255] (like Pascal syntax)?

Comment: You won't. You can use Pascal instead, though.

Comment: So pointer like &ar[1] must be equal to ar.

Comment: Some third party program is written on C. And I need to rewrite it. If I will use Pascal, it is the same as write this program by myself. I do not need to rewrite all program on Pascal. I need to rewrite piece of code.

Comment: What does having to re-write a C program have to do with 1-based array indexing?

Comment: I have own code (written on Pascal), which I must to include to C-program.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is from zero and you can't change the syntax. that been said what you can do is define a const and use it as such. 
Be aware that you are going to get a lot of people confused when they read\fix you code.
That is the reason why you can't change it.